# Conflict between the custom authController and the laravel ui loginController

Tags: laravel

After I implemented email verification and installed laravel/ui, the issue arose.

and when l put the `middleware('auth')`

Instead of the `/auth/login` that I had previously implemented, it redirected me to `/login`.

All I want to do is switch my own auth routes from the laravel ui auth routes.

web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\InterestController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SendMessageController;
use App\Http\Controllers\VerificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ForgotPasswordController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [Controller::class, 'welcome']);

Route::get('/user/register',[AuthController::class,'create']);

Route::post('/user/register',[AuthController::class,'store']);

Route::get('/auth/login',[AuthController::class,'login'])->name('login');

Route::post('/auth/signin',[AuthController::class,'signin']);

Route::post('/auth/logout',[AuthController::class,'logout']);

Route::get('/posts',[PostController::class,'index'])->middleware('verified');

Route::get('/posts/new',[PostController::class,'create']);

Route::post('/post/new',[PostController::class,'store']);
Route::get('/posts/{id}',[PostController::class,'show'])->where('id','[0-9]+');


Route::post('/post/{id}/comment', [PostController::class, 'store_comment']);

Route::post('/interest/post/{id}',[InterestController::class,'store'])->where('id','[0-9]+')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/user/post/interest',[InterestController::class,'index']);

Route::get('/user/profile', [UserController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/user/profile/settings',[UserController::class,'settings']);
Route::post('/user/profile/settings/storeprofile', [UserController::class,'storeProfile']);
Route::post('/user/profile/settings/changepassword', [UserController::class,'changePassword']);
Route::post('/user/profile/settings/emailchange',[UserController::class,'changeEmail']);

Route::post("/send",[SendMessageController::class,'sendMessage']);

Route::get("/chat",[SendMessageController::class,'show_chat']);
//show room  
Route::get("/chat/{id}",[SendMessageController::class,'show_room']);


//read_messages 
Route::post("/read_all",[SendMessageController::class,'read_all_messages']);


Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
  
    Route::get('/email/verify', [VerificationController::class,'show'])->name('verification.notice');
    Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerificationController::class,'verify'])->name('verification.verify')->middleware(['signed']);
    Route::post('/email/resend', [VerificationController::class,'resend'])->name('verification.resend');
   
});


Route::get('forget-password', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showForgetPasswordForm'])->name('forget.password.get');
Route::post('forget-password', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'submitForgetPasswordForm'])->name('forget.password.post'); 
Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showResetPasswordForm'])->name('reset.password.get');
Route::post('reset-password', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'submitResetPasswordForm'])->name('reset.password.post');
```

Errors when (php artisan route:list)

```
  ReflectionException 

  Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController" does not exist

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:234
    230▕             if ($this->isFrameworkController($route)) {
    231▕                 return false;
    232▕             }
    233▕ 
  ➜ 234▕             $path = (new ReflectionClass($route->getControllerClass()))
    235▕                                 ->getFileName();
    236▕         } else {
    237▕             return false;
    238▕         }

      +3 vendor frames 
  4   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

      +17 vendor frames 
  22  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Error in the browser please note that l dont use this controller for auth and login l use AuthController that l implemented

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist.
```

Comment: `Route::get('login',function(){ return redirect()->route('login'); });`

Comment: @WahyuKristianto l tried that but still same error 
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist.

Comment: After read your update.. you can remove the `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`

Comment: @WahyuKristianto after debuging the problem isnt from Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); it from laravel/ui

Comment: @WahyuKristianto l created the controller and made it redirect to auth/login route